# Get exactly data from php into jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a button that triggers onclick function, it calls an ajax and go to the php process the data from the database and pass back to jquery. The problem comes with it retrieves all the data fine in PHP when I echo out the data, but it seems to be sorting the data automatically by the id in jquery. How can I disable the sorting and return the exact sequence data?

If the php page generates

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [agent_id] => 1
        [details] => Array
            (
                [1] => 100
                [3] => -10
                [2] => 0
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [agent_id] => 3
        [details] => Array
            (
                [1] => 0
                [3] => -5
                [2] => -50
            )

    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [agent_id] => 2
        [details] => Array
            (
                [1] => 50
                [3] => 0
                [2] => 0
            )

    )
```

After console in jquery, it sorts it by id become to.

```
1: {agent_id: 1, details: {…}}
2: {agent_id: 2, details: {…}}
3: {agent_id: 3, details: {…}}
```

Comment: JQuery wouldn't on its own sort incoming data. Show your php, and javascript code

Comment: are u echo the data after json_encode ?

Comment: "it calls an ajax and go to the php process the data from the database and pass back to jquery". What are you doing in your PHP-code after retrieving the data?.

Comment: @shafeequeTP ya.